# Inner most dimension of an Array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

Which dimension of the array is called the innermost dimension of the array?
I was going through some tensorflow documentation ["ctc loss"](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_loss) where they describe one jargon called innermost dimension of the array. 
According to me, there can be three possibilities for the answer.
1. leftmost if see from the right.
2. rightmost if we see from the left.
3. Middle, if we see from both side.

Can someone please explain [what innermost dimension means here?](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_loss). Thanks for going through my doubt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we refer to the `tensorflow` [repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.proto), we can get the answer:

> // The order of entries in "dim" matters: It indicates the layout of
>   the
>   // values in the tensor in-memory representation.
>   //
>   // The
>   first entry in "dim" is the outermost dimension used to layout the
>   // values, the **last entry is the innermost dimension**.  This matches
>   the
>   // in-memory layout of RowMajor Eigen tensors.

(emphasis mine)

This is the same as the default (row-major, also called C-style) layout of `numpy` arrays, where the last dimension is considered the innermost because it [varies the fastest](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/glossary.html#term-row-major).

Comment: If the answer helped you please consider accepting and upvoting it

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, innermost in this documentation was used for the last dimension in the array.
In the case of tensorflow, one thing for sure, code comment do better works then the documentation. Official documentation of tensorflow still sucks.